# Prevent webbrowser send requests to css file

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I want to create webbrowser (with the help of .Net Webbrowser control) whose requests can be controlled.
for example,
I could manage to prevent image load by removing img src.
But I am not able to find some way to limit request of webbrowser control for css files, js files and requests to image files used in CSS file.
This restriction is conditional. For some website I want everything natural but for some web site it should be configurable.

> Reason: Want to send less requests to server, increase response time and reduce the traffic.

I am using below code to prevent loading images. Same way I want some logic which will prevent sending requests to css or any other files that I can decide.

```
private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement imgElemt in webBrowser1.Document.Images)
                {
                    if (imgElemt.Id == "divImagePath")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    imgElemt.SetAttribute("src", "");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is a question with a potentially massively long answer - why don't you post what you've coded so far, and ask a specific question about the code?

Answer (score -1):

You would be better off to use the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to request the page.  That way you would get the web page served to you. You could parse the page for what you do want from the site and request those items the same way.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

try 
{
  // Make an asynchronous call to get the web page
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.msn.com/");
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  // Do something more useful with the returned page
  Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
}  
catch(HttpRequestException e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!"); 
  Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
}

// Need to call dispose on the HttpClient object when we 
// are done using it, so the app doesn't leak resources
client.Dispose(true);
```

If you need to display what you have pulled, you could show it in a WebBrowser control on a form.  But that will pull all of the content associated with the page.

Comment: I have good hands on on HttpWebRequest. But I want solution with WebBrowser control only. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Isn't the point of using the WebBrowser control is for it to act like a full web browser? That would include getting all of the stuff the web page says it needs. It is possible to do what you want, but you would have to overload/override so much of the interface that it would be simpler to start from scratch.

Comment: Perfectly fine. But I am not sure from where do I start. 
I also thought about a Proxy server where I will get all the requests from browser and then I will only allow the requests I want. But the problem is that I know only C# and not sure if any open source C# proxy server code is available.
Do you know anyone?

Comment: That would be a different question. You can use either the code above (if you desire asynchronous web reads) or the HttpWebRequest (for synchronous web reads) as the basis of a replacement of the WebBrowser control. Use the above code to issue a request for the web page you desire. Once it has returned (that would be just before Console.WriteLine(responseBody);), display it in whatever format you desire. Parse the page to determine what else you might need to get (CSS, Javascript, etc.). Fetch those when/if you need them. Rinse and repeat as required.